# How to write this assertion in in first order logic?

Tags: logic

Can anybody give me an idea of how to write this assertion in first order logic.

```
X has not passed one or more of the prerequisites for A? Where X is a person name and A is the constant (course name).
```

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
∃x,y IsStudent(x) ∧ IsPrerequisite(y, A) => ¬Passes(x, y)
```